# move group python interface error

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_implboost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error >'
what():  boost: mutex lock failed in pthread_mutex_lock: Invalid argument

I'm getting this error when i tried to run the python program to move the robot in rviz. And also where is the move_group_interface.cpp file in the pr2_moveit_tutorial package in ros indigo. I wanted to move the pr2 in gazebo also not just in rviz but i'm not finding the cpp file, python file is present their but its not working. What should i do.
I installed the pr2_moveit_package as : `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-moveit-pr2`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251833/move-group-python-interface-error/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2017-01-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
@q1
A while ago I ran into the same throw, if you look closely you'll see it happens when your script is terminated.

It is a known bug, please see:
https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/331

See also the note in the tutorials under "running the code"  http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/scripts/doc/move_group_python_interface_tutorial.html

Hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [mpjansen](https://answers.ros.org/users/28366/mpjansen/) with karma: 18 on 2017-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0